# Auto submit form and retrieve form data using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm looking to create a form that uses radio buttons but as soon as a radio button is clicked it runs a JavaScript function that retrieves data from the form inducing hidden values.

I was thinking it should be something like this but I've had no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function submitFunction(formname) {
        $(".submit").onclick(function(formname) {
               var hiddenValue = document.formname.hidden_value.value;
               var vote = document.formname.vote.value;
               var dataString = 'vote=' + vote + 'hiddenValue=' + hiddenValue;

               alert(dataString);
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="post"  name="form1" >
    <input type=hidden name='hidden_value' value='12345'>
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='yes' onclick='submitFunction(form1)';>Yes <br/>
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='no' onclick='submitFunction(form1)';>No
</form>
```

**Edit:** After some help from a reply on here I have some new code. It worked perfectly on jsFiddle but no luck when I implemented it myself. I made sure that jQuery is loading properly and it is version 1.51. Here is the code. Thanks in advance again.

JavaScript:

```
     if(jQuery){
         alert("jQuery Here");
     }

    $("input.liveRadio1").click(function() {
        var jThis = $(this);

        var hiddenValue = jThis.siblings('input[name="hidden_value"]').val();
        var vote = jThis.val();
        var dataString = 'vote=' + vote + 'hiddenValue=' + hiddenValue;

        alert(dataString);
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <form action="post"  name="form1" >
        <input type=hidden name='hidden_value' value='12345' />
        <input class="liveRadio1" type='radio' name='vote' value='yes' />Yes <br/>
        <input class="liveRadio1" type='radio' name='vote' value='no' />No
    </form>
```

Comment: You're attaching an onclick handler to anything with a "submit" class, but nothing in your html has a submit class. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple; Don't use `onclick` and you don't need `submitFunction` for the posted code.
This should work:
**[See it in action at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFamB/1/).**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $("input.liveRadio1").click (function () {
        var jThis       = $(this);
        var hiddenValue = jThis.siblings ('input[name="hidden_value"]').val ();
        var vote        = jThis.val ();
        var dataString  = 'vote=' + vote + 'hiddenValue=' + hiddenValue;

        alert(dataString);
    });
</script>

<form action="post"  name="form1" >
    <input type=hidden name='hidden_value' value='12345'>
    <input class="liveRadio1" type='radio' name='vote' value='yes'>Yes <br/>
    <input class="liveRadio1" type='radio' name='vote' value='no'>No
</form>
```

---

### Additional answer for the revised question:

The code doesn't work in the standalone file because enough time was not allowed for jQuery, and the DOM, to initialize.

The standard way to do that is to use the `ready` event.  Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jQueryMain ()
    {
        $("input.liveRadio1").click(function() {
            var jThis       = $(this);
            var hiddenValue = jThis.siblings('input[name="hidden_value"]').val();
            var vote        = jThis.val();
            var dataString  = 'vote= ' + vote + ', hiddenValue= ' + hiddenValue;

            alert(dataString);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready (jQueryMain);
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. It works great on jsFiddle but no luck when I put it into it's own file. Any ideas? I have posed the code in my original post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JWH89, See the extra section I added to my answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass it form1 in

```
onclick='submitFunction(form1)';
```

because you are accessing it in the submit. Although I think having that submit function in the other function might screw it up because when you click the radio button you haven't pressed submit, so that function in submitFunction will never trigger.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the way you create your function, the correct should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function submitFunction(formname) {
        $('#' + formname).submit();
    }
</script>

<form action="post" id="form1" >
    <input type=hidden name='hidden_value' value='12345'>
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='yes' onclick='submitFunction('form1')';>Yes <br/>
    <input type='radio' name='vote' value='no' onclick='submitFunction('form1')';>No
</form>
```